# How to reduce properties of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have AJAX call to retrieve some documents. This documents have large amount of attributes which are not needed for me. Is there a way to simply reduce properties of objects in array so I don't need to sen large JSON, but instead to send only properties which are indeed needed for me. I know that I can make it with `for` loop, but I'm asking if there is some built-in way of doing it?

Something like:

```
array.attributes('title','date');
```

(I know I can make utility like that and add method to an array, but still I am asking if there is already built-in way of doing this)

Comment: Why not just send less data?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to reduce it on client side, but on server side.

Comment: Once you get it on the client side, there is no point in reducing. It's even more CPU/memory intensive to reduce it.

Comment: Once again, that's exactly what I was saying. I'm trying to reduce it before it comes to the client side so the data needed to be sent is minimised.

Comment: Okay, so how are you sending it? You've not given us much information on your environment here.